# svg блок со срезанными и скругленными углами

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть такой блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой svg:

```css
.box {
 position: relative;
 margin: .75em auto 0;
 max-width: 255px;
 min-height: 56px;
}

svg {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
 <svg>
  <mask id='m' fill='#fff'>
   <rect id='r' width='256' height='56'/>
   <circle id='c' r='10' fill='#000'/>
   <use xlink:href='#c' x='100%'/>
   <use xlink:href='#c' y='100%'/>
   <use xlink:href='#c' x='100%' y='100%'/>
  </mask>
  
  <mask id='m2' fill='#fff'>
   <rect id='r2' width='248' height='50' x="4" y="4" />
   <circle id='c2' r='14' fill='#000' stroke='#000'/>
   <use xlink:href='#c2' x='100%' />
   <use xlink:href='#c2' y='100%'/>
   <use xlink:href='#c2' x='100%' y='100%'/>
  </mask>
  
  <use xlink:href='#r' fill='red' mask='url(#m)'/>
  <use xlink:href='#r2' fill='none' stroke="#000" mask='url(#m2)'/>
 </svg>
</div>
```

**Вопрос:** как сделать внутри блок с такими же скругленными срезанными углами, но не  со сплошной заливкой а обводкой?

P.S: при этом должна остаться возможность редактирования радиуса скруглений углов, отступы вн. блоков. Возможно есть простая реализация на css (максимально кроссбраузерная), тоже подошло бы.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/a/53394384/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Примерно так

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 353 205" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

 <g transform="translate(194 -58)">
  <g transform="matrix(5.2 0 0 5.7 -199 -800)">
   <path d="m19 160c0-1.1 0.047-1.5 0.1-0.99 0.057 0.55 0.057 1.4 0 2s-0.1 0.099-0.1-0.99zm4.5 1.2c-0.0054-0.44 0.049-0.65 0.12-0.47 0.072 0.18 0.077 0.54 0.0098 0.79-0.067 0.26-0.13 0.11-0.13-0.33zm2.1 0.41c0-0.14 0.12-0.32 0.26-0.41 0.15-0.093 0.19 0.014 0.1 0.25-0.18 0.46-0.37 0.54-0.37 0.16zm2.2-1.3c0-0.95 0.048-1.3 0.11-0.86 0.059 0.47 0.059 1.2 0 1.7-0.059 0.47-0.11 0.086-0.11-0.86zm3.4 0.29c0-0.78-0.13-1.3-0.32-1.4-0.21-0.07-0.18-0.16 0.09-0.26 0.33-0.13 0.42 0.12 0.46 1.4 0.031 0.86-0.0094 1.6-0.09 1.6-0.08 0-0.15-0.59-0.15-1.3zm4.3 0.64c-0.0054-0.44 0.049-0.65 0.12-0.47 0.072 0.18 0.077 0.54 0.0098 0.79-0.067 0.26-0.13 0.11-0.13-0.33zm4.5-1.2c0-1.1 0.047-1.5 0.1-0.99 0.057 0.55 0.057 1.4 0 2s-0.1 0.099-0.1-0.99zm2.1 0.26c0-0.95 0.048-1.3 0.11-0.86 0.059 0.47 0.059 1.2 0 1.7-0.059 0.47-0.11 0.086-0.11-0.86zm3.2 0c0-0.95 0.048-1.3 0.11-0.86 0.059 0.47 0.059 1.2 0 1.7-0.059 0.47-0.11 0.086-0.11-0.86zm1.3-0.32c0.045-1.8 0.058-1.8 0.15-0.48 0.055 0.8 0.2 1.5 0.32 1.6 0.12 0.076 0.054 0.29-0.15 0.48-0.31 0.29-0.36 0.047-0.32-1.6zm2.7 0.056c0-1.1 0.047-1.5 0.1-0.99 0.057 0.55 0.057 1.4 0 2s-0.1 0.099-0.1-0.99zm0.79 0c0-1.1 0.047-1.5 0.1-0.99 0.057 0.55 0.057 1.4 0 2s-0.1 0.099-0.1-0.99zm2.1 0.93c-0.0029-0.58 0.049-0.85 0.12-0.6 0.066 0.25 0.069 0.73 0.0053 1.1-0.063 0.33-0.12 0.12-0.12-0.46zm-23-1.5c0-0.8 0.05-1.1 0.11-0.73 0.061 0.4 0.061 1.1 0 1.5s-0.11 0.073-0.11-0.73zm14 0.92c-0.091-0.24-0.15-0.87-0.13-1.4 0.032-0.87 0.056-0.83 0.23 0.35 0.2 1.4 0.17 1.7-0.097 1zm-20-1.2c-0.056-0.58-0.0085-1.1 0.1-1.1 0.11 0 0.21 0.48 0.21 1.1 0 0.58-0.047 1.1-0.1 1.1s-0.15-0.48-0.21-1.1zm3 0.26c0-0.51 0.054-0.72 0.12-0.46 0.067 0.25 0.067 0.67 0 0.93s-0.12 0.046-0.12-0.46zm9-0.4c-0.0029-0.58 0.049-0.85 0.12-0.6 0.066 0.25 0.069 0.73 0.0053 1.1-0.063 0.33-0.12 0.12-0.12-0.46zm-11 0.4c0-0.15 0.052-0.26 0.12-0.26 0.064 0 0.19 0.12 0.28 0.26 0.09 0.15 0.037 0.26-0.12 0.26-0.15 0-0.28-0.12-0.28-0.26zm8.8-0.53c0-0.51 0.054-0.72 0.12-0.46 0.067 0.25 0.067 0.67 0 0.93s-0.12 0.046-0.12-0.46zm19 0c0-0.51 0.054-0.72 0.12-0.46 0.067 0.25 0.067 0.67 0 0.93s-0.12 0.046-0.12-0.46zm-35-0.13c-0.0054-0.44 0.05-0.65 0.12-0.47s0.077 0.54 0.0098 0.79c-0.067 0.26-0.13 0.11-0.13-0.33z"/>
   <path d="m29 162c-0.084-0.14-0.051-0.31 0.073-0.39 0.12-0.076 0.22 0.034 0.22 0.25 0 0.45-0.083 0.49-0.3 0.14zm14 0.086c0-0.22 0.51-0.34 0.63-0.15 0.076 0.12-0.034 0.22-0.25 0.22-0.21 0-0.39-0.033-0.39-0.073zm-8.2-1.1c0-0.22 0.51-0.34 0.63-0.15 0.076 0.12-0.034 0.22-0.25 0.22-0.21 0-0.39-0.033-0.39-0.073zm3.4-0.088c0-0.14 0.12-0.32 0.26-0.41 0.15-0.093 0.19 0.014 0.1 0.25-0.18 0.46-0.37 0.54-0.37 0.16zm-18-1.1c-0.09-0.15-0.037-0.26 0.12-0.26 0.15 0 0.28 0.12 0.28 0.26s-0.052 0.26-0.12 0.26c-0.064 0-0.19-0.12-0.28-0.26z"/>
   <path d="m51 160c0.25-0.066 0.67-0.066 0.93 0 0.25 0.067 0.046 0.12-0.46 0.12-0.51 0-0.72-0.054-0.46-0.12z"/>
   <path d="m21 161c0.088-0.088 0.32-0.097 0.51-0.021 0.21 0.084 0.15 0.15-0.16 0.16-0.28 0.012-0.44-0.051-0.35-0.14zm17 0c0.088-0.088 0.32-0.097 0.51-0.021 0.21 0.084 0.15 0.15-0.16 0.16-0.28 0.012-0.44-0.051-0.35-0.14zm-11-1.9c0.18-0.073 0.48-0.073 0.66 0s0.033 0.13-0.33 0.13c-0.36 0-0.51-0.06-0.33-0.13zm14-7e-3c0.25-0.066 0.67-0.066 0.93 0 0.25 0.067 0.046 0.12-0.46 0.12-0.51 0-0.72-0.054-0.46-0.12zm3.6 7e-3c0.18-0.073 0.48-0.073 0.66 0s0.033 0.13-0.33 0.13c-0.36 0-0.51-0.06-0.33-0.13z" />
   <path d="m3 167c0-0.59-1.1-1.6-1.7-1.6-0.4 0-0.45-0.51-0.45-5.3 0-4.9 0.031-5.3 0.48-5.3 0.59 0 1.6-1.1 1.6-1.7 0-0.42 2.2-0.45 32-0.45 31 0 32 0.018 32 0.48 0 0.59 1.1 1.6 1.7 1.6 0.4 0 0.45 0.51 0.45 5.3 0 4.9-0.031 5.3-0.48 5.3-0.59 0-1.6 1.1-1.6 1.7 0 0.42-2.2 0.45-32 0.45-31 0-32-0.018-32-0.48zm63-0.98c0.14-0.37 0.55-0.78 0.92-0.92l0.67-0.25v-9.6l-0.67-0.25c-0.37-0.14-0.78-0.55-0.92-0.92l-0.25-0.67h-62l-0.25 0.67c-0.14 0.37-0.55 0.78-0.92 0.92l-0.67 0.25v9.6l0.67 0.25c0.37 0.14 0.78 0.55 0.92 0.92l0.25 0.67h62zm-62-0.26c-0.17-0.37-0.6-0.8-0.97-0.97l-0.67-0.3v-8.8l0.67-0.3c0.37-0.17 0.8-0.6 0.97-0.97l0.3-0.67h61l0.3 0.67c0.17 0.37 0.6 0.8 0.97 0.97l0.67 0.3v8.8l-0.67 0.3c-0.37 0.17-0.8 0.6-0.97 0.97l-0.3 0.67h-61z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: возможно есть какой то редактор svg в котором эта опция есть но в illustrator corel draw или в inkscape такой опции не существует

Comment: Опция?)))) Нет такой опции нет, Ваша идея мне понятна  - нарисовать от руки. Такой подход не подходит.

Comment: в corel draw есть такая штука

Answer (score 4):

*Этот ответ публикуется, чтобы сделать ассоциацию с Enso, где автором данного вопроса был задан аналогичный вопрос и был получен отличный ответ от `@Paul LeBeau`*

Основная идея,- использование сложной маски, составленной из окружностей, которые вырезают из прямоугольника, четверть круга по углам, образуя тем самым закругления.

```css
.box {
 position: relative;
 margin: .75em auto 0;
 width: 255px;
 height: 56px;
}

.box svg {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.size2 {
 width: 455px;
 height: 256px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <mask id="m" fill="#fff">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>

      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="12"/>
      <circle r="16" fill="#000"/>
      <circle cx="100%" r="16" fill="#000"/>
      <circle cy="100%" r="16" fill="#000"/>
      <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="16" fill="#000"/>

      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="8"/>
      <circle r="14" fill="#fff"/>
      <circle cx="100%" r="14" fill="#fff"/>
      <circle cy="100%" r="14" fill="#fff"/>
      <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="14" fill="#fff"/>

      <circle r="10" fill="#000"/>
      <circle cx="100%" r="10" fill="#000"/>
      <circle cy="100%" r="10" fill="#000"/>
      <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="10" fill="#000"/>
    </mask>
  
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#m)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53394384/7394871)

Вариант использования вырезания маской, но несколько другие позиции окружностей в маске и получилась футболка:

```css
.box {
 position: relative;
 margin: .75em auto 0;
 width: 155px;
 height: 256px;
}

.box svg {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.size2 {
 width: 455px;
 height: 256px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <mask id="m" fill="#fff">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>

      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="12"/>
      <circle cx="-5%"  cy="7%" r="32" fill="#000"/>
      <circle cx="105%" cy="7%" r="32" fill="#000"/>
      <circle cx="50%" cy="5%" r="36" fill="#000"/>
      
    </mask>
  
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#m)" fill="purple"/> 
 
 <text x="8%" y="45%" font-size="28" font-weight="700"  fill="white">I love SVG</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: ждала-ждала лучшего ответа от @Alexandr_TT, а он мне ассоциацию )))))

Comment: @HamSter Меня долго не было, только вечером приехал. Начал писать ответ и тоже с масками,  зашёл на ENso и увидел твой вопрос и ответ. Сейчас добавлю вариант маечку, с той же техникой

Comment: @HamSter  и я ьак и не понял для чего такие трудности - всё равно каждую окружность редактировать придётся по отдельности - `велосипед нового поколения`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  сможешь сказать по этому [поводу](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53455516/10697995) ?

Comment: @Nikita я поставил вам плюс за работу. Но посмотрите объективно. В вашем варианте, чтобы изменить очертания фигуры, в случае необходимости, нужно в редакторе снова рисовать. В варианте с масками достаточно изменить радиусы и позиционирование окружностей.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я же там нарисовал уже два состояния до и после, я потому и спросил - как это реализовать ?

Comment: @Nikita я отвечал на твой комментарий -`велосипед нового поколения`а не на вопрос на Enso.  В том вопросе надо анимировать параметр "d" патча. Размести у нас вопрос наверняка ответят

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  у нас здесь только минусы ставят ...ладно спасибо за помощь

Comment: с майкой интересно, но проблема не в том чтобы сам блок такой формы создать,  а в том чтобы создать обводку такой формы и при этом была бы возможность редактировать радиус скруглений и толщину обводки

Comment: потому как пока пришла к этому варианту https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/BGJaVx просто подбирала значения ...